# jQuery function only affecting one img out of 3

Tags: jquery

This is a follow up from a question I asked earlier but although mostly working now, the function is taking the first of 3 images as it's reference to `addClass()` and not following the `if / else`. Any idea why?

Image 1 & 3 = Landscape - correctly adding `.heightDefine`

Image 2 = Portrait - incorrectly also adding `.heightDefine` instead of `.widthDefine`

```
jQuery.fn.galDisplay = function () {
    var galSingleImgH = this.height();
    var galSingleImgW = this.width();
    if(galSingleImgW > galSingleImgH){
        this.addClass('heightDefine');
    } else if(galSingleImgW < galSingleImgH){
        this.addClass('widthDefine');
    } 
}
jQuery('.notFirst img').galDisplay();
```

Comment: It's not an if-else, it's an if-else if. One of those statements have to be true, or none will occur. If it was an if-else, then at least one of those statements will be executed.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What are the values of of `galSingleImgW` and `galSingleImgH`?

Comment: You are missing the case galSingleImgW = galSingleImgH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery will actually give you a collection of matching elements, so `this` is the collection, not a single result.

To deal with this, iterate the collection using `each`:

```
jQuery.fn.galDisplay = function () {
    this.each(function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        var galSingleImgH = $self.height();
        var galSingleImgW = $self.width();
        alert(galSingleImgW + ' ' + galSingleImgH);
        if(galSingleImgW > galSingleImgH){
            $self.addClass('heightDefine');
        } else if(galSingleImgW < galSingleImgH){
            $self.addClass('widthDefine');
        } 
        // else it is square!
    });
}
jQuery('.notFirst img').galDisplay();
```

And the only other thing I would add is that if you are relying on working out the image size you don't want to run this until the image is loaded.

Comment: +1 to you to, especially for getting the accepted answer, when it was posted ten minutes after the rest, not bad :-) ...

Answer (score 2):

You're running the same function on the whole collection, you need to run the if/else on each element:

```
jQuery.fn.galDisplay = function (){
    return this.each(function() {
        var galSingleImgH = $(this).height(),
            galSingleImgW = $(this).width();

        if (galSingleImgW > galSingleImgH) {
            $(this).addClass('heightDefine');
        } else if (galSingleImgW < galSingleImgH) {
            $(this).addClass('widthDefine');
        } 
    });
}

jQuery('.notFirst img').galDisplay();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.galDisplay = function(params)
    {
        //params = $.extend( {minlength: 0, maxlength: 99999}, params);
        //above code extends options passed

        this.each(function()
        {
            var galSingleImgH = this.height();
            var galSingleImgW = this.width();
            if(galSingleImgW > galSingleImgH)
            {
               this.addClass('heightDefine');
            }
            else if(galSingleImgW < galSingleImgH)
            {
               this.addClass('widthDefine');
            } 
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```